# how to Calculate trigonometric ratio using series sinx = x - (x3/3)! + (x5/5)i - (x7/7)! + a in c program

Tags: c

I want to calculate trigonometric ratio in c using series

```
 sinx = x - x3/3! + x5/5! - x7/7! + a
```

and want to compare my result with standard math lib function.
where a = constant

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is how to sum up the series, you could just update the term one by one:

```
double sum_the_series(double x, size_t number_of_terms)
{
  const double x2 = x * x;

  double term = x;
  double result = term;

  for (size_t i = 1; i < number_of_terms; ++i)
  {
    term = term * x2 / (double(2*i) * double(2*i+1));
    if (i % 2 == 0) result += t;
    else            result -= t;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. It's orders of magnitude faster - not to mention simpler - than the accepted solution, which is a textbook example of bad factorization.

Comment: straightforward and naif, a direct translation of the mathematical formula; this is the correct definition of "my" textbook solution. And it is why it is easier to be understood; of course Kerrek SB's solution is better for practical purposes (!) and it is a good fellow for my answer.

Comment: Anyone doing it on paper as a math exercise would do it Kerrek's way, not your way, ShinTakezou.

Comment: and how can you be sure about this claim? a mathematician with few programming knowledge and no interest in optimization can likely produce a naive direct translation of the math formula. After, s/he can make it better. But this is not the point of the question, since the OP wants just to compare (the result), not to compute it efficiently. It seems to me that "If the question is how to sum up the series" has as answer false (the question is not how to sum up the series efficiently, anyway). But you can continue arguing it it if you want

Comment: If you're doing arithmetic on paper, you're surely not going to start from scratch each time computing x^n or n!. Even if you start out doing things that way, if you have any talent for mathematical thinking at all you'll realize the redundancy after one or two steps and switch to using running products.

Comment: I have not said the mathematician would start computing it by hand. He has a beautiful formula, and he tries to say to a computer how to compute it; many of them do not know tricks and limits about IEEE fp; some come in contact with "computational" problems just because of the "branch" of mathematics they chose, others do not; many in my experience have no programming skills at all; though of course can understand the problem behind this implementation, they at first won't code it in the optimized way even if, when forced to compute it by hand, would do the "right" thing.

Answer (score 1):

Factorial tends to become huge very fast (12! does not fit into a 32 bit variable); if you don't care too much about precision details and more, you can implement it *very* naively like

```
   double fact(unsigned int n)
   {
      double r = 1.0;
      if (n == 0 || n == 1) return 1.0;
      // memoizing here can help
      while(n-- > 0) r *= (double)(n+1);
      return r;
   }

   double part(double x, int n)
   {
      return (n%2 == 0? -1 : 1)*pow(x, 2*n - 1)/fact(2*n-1); 
   }

   double sinx(double x)
   {
      static const double a = 0.0020202; // a number
      int i;
      double r = 0.0;
      for (i = 1; i < MAXP; i++)
         r += part(x, i);
      return r + a;
   }
```

or something like this (I have no tested it). Of course, it is not the exact way sin can be computed correctly.

---

Apart from the use of the function *part*, which holds a single "term" of the sum, this is a direct (naive) obvious translation of the mathematical formula. Let us see how to put the formula in a way that it is better to be implemented and has better performance though, to taste any difference you need to compute likely 1M sin-s or more. (This SO does not understand TeX markup as other SO sites?)

```
x0 = x = x/1!
x1 = -x^3/3! = -x/1!  *  x^2/(2 * 3) = x0 * x^2/(2 * 3)
x2 = x^5/5!  = x^3/3!  *  x^2/(4 * 5)  =  -x1 * x^2/(4 * 5)
x3 = -x^7/7! = -x^5/5!  *  x^2/(6 * 7) =  -x2 * x^2/(6 * 7)
.
.
.
xn = -x(n-1) * x^2/(2n * (2n + 1))   for n > 0
```

The code given in the other answer is the translation of this "formula", not of the original one. So the code, translating this formula, would be as the other answer, more or less:

```
double sinx(double x, size_t t)
{
   double term = x;
   double result = term;
   size_t i;

   for(i = 1; i < t; i++)
   {
      term *= -x*x/( (double)(2*i*(2*i + 1)) );
      result += term;
   }

   return current + trunc_err(x, t);
}
```

where trunc_err is a function that computes the error because of the truncation of the serie. (As before, checking if everything is right is left as an exercise)

Comment: One objection - the utility of memoization is usually a sign of bad design. In this case it comes from badly factoring your function. If your `sinx` function needs the factorials `(2n+1)!` in sequence, it should simply keep a running variable itself, rather than forcing another function to be inefficient in either time or space to make up for not being aware of the caller's usage pattern.

Comment: And likewise with your inefficient computation of powers.

Comment: @R.. and more: "if you don't care too much about precision details and more". I think your running variable as a special case of memoization. Why haven't you pointed out that computing sin(x) this way is anyway not the right way, and  sin(x) algorithms do not use this approach at all? For the purpose of the user, this is straightforward and ok, though naif (as said)

Comment: OP specifically mentioned wanting to compare Taylor sums to the standard library's `sin` function, presumably either for computational-mathematics purposes or just to get a feel for how quickly the sums converge. If OP were asking how to compute sin(x), I would not recommend Taylor series. Regardless, for a given mathematical approach, there are efficient and inefficient implementations and yours is about the worst you can make it and very bad advice for new programmers.

Comment: so, you are saying (and agree with me) that pointing out that taylor is not the best way is pointless (!) since the OP explicitly said/specified something. if you need more explanation: for the same reason your points about my answer are pointless: "if you don't care too much about precision details and more, you can implement it *very* naively"... should I have used bold for "naively"?

Comment: Computing Taylor sums is a valid thing to do. It's not a good way to compute sin(x) but there are plenty of other good reasons you might want to compute a Taylor sum for sin(x). On the other hand, factoring your code incorrectly so that it's orders of magnitude slower than a much simpler implementation has no purpose. The reason I was so harsh on your about this is that **lots of newbie coders** write badly factored code exactly like you did, and it should be critiqued on a site that's about helping people learn.

Comment: still pointless, for the aim of the OP (comparing, not having good algo), unless s/he compute 1M sin... otherwise you won't notice the diff in performance. Moreover, though naive, it's the best starting point for newbie coders. Starting with naive implementation, to show its weak points and how to improve, not just showing the "actual" algo. Moreover, as the Q is given, it seems more a curiosity, maybe by a person not interested to be a coder at all. And if it is homework (missing tag), s/he'll be interested in both answers (though mine was buggy, and the other won't compile)

Comment: That's my point - your implementation is not the "naive" one, it's the "overfactored, and incorrectly so" version. Factoring it the way you did bloated the code and made it *less obvious* how to accomplish the task.

Comment: not at all: it is the perfect naive implementation: it is a direct translation of the formula. And it is the *top most obvious* way to sum that summation! I dont understand how you may think it is not. If you wish, call it the wrong way, but it is for sure the most straightforward way to write that formula, exactly as "it is" its mathematical counterpart. In fact, the given formula can be "refactored", and the "correct" algo is a direct translation of the "refactored" (set of) formula(e), in which each term is written as "function" of the previous term, hence the "generalization" and the loop.

Comment: so, the "correct" ansswer is the implementation of another "formula", which is a "refactoring" of the given and well known one. Therefore, since the formula the code is the translation of is not shown, and anyway it would require a "refactoring" step of the original formula, that code cant be the "obvious" way to accomplish the task.