# Calculating mathematical constant e using while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am currently doing a task in a book which asks me to calculate the mathematical constant e using the while loop. I managed that fairly easily, however I am having troubles calculating e^x, whereas the user inputs x and the degree of accuracy. The code I used for computing e is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int degreeOfAccuracy, x = 1;
long double e = 1;
cout << "Enter degree of accuracy of mathimatical constant e: ";
cin >> degreeOfAccuracy;
while (x <= degreeOfAccuracy)
{
      int conter = x;
      int intial = x;
      long double number = x;
      int counter = 1;
      while (conter > 1)
      {
             number = number*(intial-counter);
             counter++;
             conter--;
      }
      e += (1/number);
      x++;
}
cout << endl << "The mathematical constantr e is: " 
     << setprecision(degreeOfAccuracy) << fixed << e << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

However, when I tried e^x the following code returned a completely wrong value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
int degreeOfAccuracy, x = 1, exponent;
long double e = 1;
cout << "Enter degree of accuracy of mathimatical constant e: ";
cin >> degreeOfAccuracy;
cout << "Enter the number of which you wish to raise to e: ";
cin >> exponent;
int temp = exponent;
while (x <= degreeOfAccuracy)
{
      exponent = temp;
      int conter = x;
      int intial = x;
      long double number = x;
      int counter = 1;
      while (conter > 1)
      {
             number = number*(intial-counter);
             counter++;
             conter--;
      }
      int counterr = 1;
      while (counterr < x)
      {
            exponent *= exponent;
            counterr++;
      }
      e += (exponent/number);
      x++;
}
cout << endl << "The mathematical constantr e is: " << setprecision(degreeOfAccuracy) << fixed << e << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Any ideas where the calculations went wrong?

Comment: How & where does it fail? At compile time? Runtime?

Comment: Please be more specific.  Did it not compile?  Did it not run?  Was the output incorrect?

Comment: exp is essentially the same as sin, so if you get stuck you can use [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496407/how-to-calculate-trigonometric-ratio-using-series-sinx-x-x3-3-x5-5i/6496740#6496740).

Comment: Sorry, i will correct "failed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
exponent *= exponent;
```

is wrong. It should be:

```
exponent *= temp;
```